# express route 404 page never got triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route like this

```
router.get('/:username', function(req, res, next) {
if(req.params.username){
      Account.find({'username':req.params.username},function(err,user){
        if(user.length > 0){
            res.render('index',{
            title:capitalizeFirstLetter(req.params.username)
          });

        }
      })
    }
});
```

and it worked whenever I put any my users' name. But If I put something which is not in the db, it load forever. I have many many routes like this, so it would be tedious if I modify each of them to go to 404 error page.

I wonder why the default 404 doesn't work anymore, which is

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

Comment: What do you render when user.length == 0?... That's the answer, I guess.

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda I have other routes like :username/profile etc, I do not want to modify every route.

Comment: you are not handling else case i.e., `user.length > 0` and as well as use `*` in error handler for any other unknown route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your approach is wrong like you are saying if I put any user then it's fine but when I put any value which is not in `db` then it stuck. Absolutely it will be stuck since you are not handling the second case or `else` case. It's not route issue route is proper but it's handle issue.

You need to handle both conditions

`Success and fail`

```
if (user.length > 0) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: capitalizeFirstLetter(req.params.username)
    });
}else{
        res.render('index', {
        title: 'Your error stuff'
    });
}
```

Other's answers are valid if `route is not found` but in your case every route found as your question says

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not handling the case when `(users.length === 0)`.

You should throw an error in that case.

Comment: your app.use() will catch any route that doesn't match /:username. But once it matches this form you check DB if it exists... even if it doesn't exist in DB it matches the route doesn't it? So you have to handle that in the route itself and there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
 var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

If you use the * symbol at the end of your routes, any unhandled routes will default to this.

Comment: what is the different of this than app.use?

Comment: Using app.use() is creating middleware which is mainly used for changing the request/data where as using router.get(*) is simply using routing and setting up a default route if the request doesn't match any others.